# Can benzene form catenanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry

With there being many particles reacting together forming different shapes of molecules, is there even a slight possibility of some cyclo or benzene miraculously forming into a chain?

Comment: You mean ring opening or chain of benzene rings? Biphenyl is made up of two benzene rings. There are natural macromolecules called polyphenols.

Comment: nope, I mean literally a chain. So Im not looking for a molecule formed by a bond, but two normal benzene molecules that happened to form going through each others doughnut holes.

Comment: you mean concatemers of benzene.. The ring is not huge enough to allow that. You generally need long polymeric loops to achieve that.

Comment: No way. There "hole" in benzene molecule is so small, we may safely assume there is no hole at all. On the other hand, chain-like compounds do exist and are known as [catenanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenane).

Comment: Thanks! Catenanes is exactly the types of structure i was talking about

Comment: oh yes it probably is.